# EFCore Disable related data from loading it's related data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-3.1

let's say i have 2 models.

**Model 1**

```
public class model1
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual model2 relatedModel2 {get;set}
}
```

**Model 2**

```
public class model2
    {
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public virtual ICollection<model1> relatedModel1 {get;set;}
    }
```

now every time i try to get model 1 and include model 2. model 2 also includs all model 1 related data as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization).

now i need to disable that. is that possible? here is how i query the data.

```
context.model1.Include(a => a.model2).toList();
```

this is the result i get.

```
[
  {
     name: 'blah blah blah',
     relatedModel2: {
         name: 'blah balh blah',
         relatedModel1: [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
     }
  }
]
```

i need to remove relatedModel1 from relatedModel2.

Update (forgot to include during first time posting this):
i already have this setup.

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
            {
                opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

Comment: May I ask why? Anyway, you can't.

Comment: Do you want to exclude the `relatedModel`` navigation property from JSON serialization?  Or do you want to ensure that it contains only a single member?

Comment: You mean you serialize it to json and need to exclude nested `relatedModel1 ` from it?

Comment: @GuruStron yes. on aspcore 3.1

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes i don't want the related data from related data. on aspcore 3.1

Comment: @GertArnold that is not true. it was not happening in aspcore 2.2

Comment: What was not happening? EF has always had relationship fixup. That can't be changed. In that sense it doesn't "happen in ASP.Net core 2.2". It happens in EF and each environment may "feel" its effect differently.

Comment: @GertArnold yeah i just added some answer below. apparently i just observed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in ConfigureServices method-

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );
```

Or Add [JsonIgnore] on top of

```
public virtual ICollection<model1> relatedModel1 {get;set;}
```

Comment: apparently i already have this on my startup.cs but for aspcore 3.1. see update on post.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, i was comparing this to my previous project which uses aspcore 2.2 version and indeed they are behaving exactly the same.

the only thing i didn't observe is the difference between retrieving all data and few data.

when i retrieve only a few data i get results and then the related data may be populated or not, it depends whether those data are related to each other. for example.

**model 1 data**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "george",
    relatedModel2: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "jason",
    relatedModel2: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "michael",
    relatedModel2: 1
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "luke",
    relatedModel2: 2
  }
]
```

**model 2**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "greg"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "martin"
  }
]
```

so when i try to retrieve all data. it also populates all related data. but when i try to retrieve let's say model1 with id in (1,2).

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "george",
    relatedModel2: {
      id: 1,
      name: "greg",
      relatedModel1: [
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "jason"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     name: "jason",
     relatedModel2: {
       id: 1,
       name: "greg",
       relatedModel1: [
         {
           id: 1,
           name: "george"
         } 
       ]
    }
  }
]
```